# Access - Form or control width doesn't update

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set listbox column widths based on the current size of the listbox, I've set it to use the `Listbox.Width` property but this never seems to update, it stays at the value set in design mode.

Even created a new form with a resize event as below:

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Text0 = CStr(Me.Width) & " - " & CStr(Rnd())
End Sub
```

And the width stays static as I resize it (the event is certainly firing as the random value changes).

Is this a know problem with Access and if so are there any work-arounds?

How can I get the current width of the control or form?

Comment: You can only change control size and position in design mode. It can be done programmatically, but it still requires exclusive access to the database, which means each user will have to have their own exclusive front end.

Comment: @Sunknight0 I don't think you read the question

Comment: Listbox boxes are sub-controls. I have never tried to dynamically adjust them, but I would expect the same rules as adjusting other control width apply. Either that o the code you are using to adjust the width (which you have not provided) is not the correct code to do so.

Comment: Btw, if the question is "why is my form width value not updating", the answer is, "I don't know, it works for me when I need to get the form width to adjust sub-form sizes".

Comment: @Sunknight0 I'm not trying to change the widths, I'm setting the `columnWidths` property, this works without issue during run time. The problem is when the form changes size, this adjusts the listbox width as it's anchored to both sides. If you then check the `Listbox.Width` property it still reports the original size.

Comment: Have you tried not using anchoring, but manually changing the size of the control? I don't use anchoring so I don't know how it works "behind the scenes". It is possible that it uses temporary values for things like `width` while the object/control maintains the original values. I generally just get the form dimensions and then manually adjust any controls that need adjusting, although admittedly I have never had to adjust listbox or combo box column widths.

Comment: Follow up question: If you adjust the column with using fixed numbers (even if the width is not what you want, just as a test) does it work? It is the fact that the control's `width` property is not updating the only issue?

Comment: @SunKnight0 Turning off anchoring doesn't help, the form size still doesn't update. Updating the control size by setting the width works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a messy work around (but I'm still open to suggestions for a better one).

The only property that seems to change on resize is the `Form.InsideWidth`.

At form load I save the difference between the Listboxes width and the inside width:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    p_ListToWindowDiff = Me.InsideWidth - Listbox1.Width
End Sub
```

Then when resized I use this to get the new listbox width:

```
NewListWidth = Me.InsideWidth - p_ListToWindowDiff
```